# how to store values in an array?

Tags: android

I have done a code for getting coordinates in surface view when we click on the  screen.My question is how to display all coordinates after releasing mouse from the screen using android.

Comment: Why would you display no never mind HOW would you like to represent the data. If its just for test use log or toast.

Comment: post some codes so that somebodybody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

My quick snippet for you :)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
         if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
         {
                 touchX = e.getX();
                 touchY = e.getY();
         }

         Toast.makeText(this, "X = " + touchX + " - Y = " + touchY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```